# Audio keeps breaking for the video created by Adobe After Effect CS 5.5

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I created a video using Adobe After Effect CS 5.5 and imported a MP3 file to the time line - After rendering the video to a movie with .avi format, the audio keeps breaking during the show time. 

basically the audio stops during the video and then starts again, stops and then starts again - it is really annoying. I tried to change it from 16 bit to 8bit and 32 bit but nothing changed - 

really appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: This seems like it should be on avp.stackexchange.com instead of superuser.

Answer (score 0):

After effects can have trouble with mp3 files, if you convert the audio files to wav that should solve your problem.